# "Мучительно быстро"

Tags: семантика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Фраза "время тянется мучительно медленно" привычна для нашего слуха. Совсем недавно услышал выражение *"мучительно **быстро** летят секунды"*. Можно ли так говорить, грамотно ли это выражение?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Не берусь высказать своё мнение, одно только хочу сказать, что мне кажется, что "мучительно медленно" скорее подходящее выражение, чем "мучительно быстро".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь о правомерности использования собственно характеристики "мучительно быстро", то это вопрос о сочетаемости. К грамотности имеет весьма косвенное отношение.

Оценка подобных сочетаний дело достаточно субъективное, к тому же нельзя сбрасывать со счетов возможность фигуры речи, например той, при которой слово из устоявшегося сочетания заменяется на противоположное (*антифразис*, что ли?! - ср. у Гоголя "все как мухи выздоравливают").

Если же все эти оговорки исключить, то в сухом остатке остается сочетание "мучительно" - семантически характеризующее именно продолжительный процесс (отсюда и "мучительно медленный") - и "быстро" с противоположной семантикой. Вот как охарактеризовать их сочетание? Явно что-то не совсем традиционное.

Увы, боюсь, что однозначного, но обоснованного ответа вам никто не даст.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо, behemothus!

Answer (score 2):

Разные бывают ситуации и ощущения:

"Постепенно, однако, оно менялось, становилось знакомым, и, под влиянием его взгляда, льдинки в груди начали вдруг **мучительно быстро** таять". [В. Г. Короленко. Мороз (1900-1901)].

Можно обсуждать смысл и точность авторского описания, а грамматика здесь обычная, стандартная, нельзя назвать ее неправильной.

Comment: Sibylla, грамматика одно, но, автор, кажется, спрашивал не о грамматике. Мне такое выражение кажется неправильным, хотя в Интернете много примеров с таким словосочетанием.

Comment: Обычно жалуются на быстротечное время, на быстро проходящую жизнь, что-то вроде " я прошу остановись на время, не беги так мучительно быстро". Такие мысли могут доставлять страдания, то есть быть мучительными для человека.